# Copy a JSON object

Tags: json

Let's say i have a JSON object:

```
myJson1={
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2
}
myJson2={};
```

and another json Object myJson2
When i run

```
myJson2 = myJson1;
```

All think goes well the first object is equal to the second.
But now if i try to use myJson2 like this,

```
var val = myJson2.key1;
console.log(val); is empty !!!
```

I have make some search and i found something about "*proto*"

Comment: Are you sure you've included the code exactly how it is? That looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: That works if by `value1` and `value2` you meant just some variable and not using those as an exact value. `value1` and `value2` are not valid. They must be one of the valid javascript [data types](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagin9 is right - make sure your assignment statement is correct. I would comment on that post, but I don't have enough rep so I'll add this here - make sure value1 and value2 are defined. By themselves, they don't mean anything. Either put them in quotes, make them ints or booleans, etc. or define them as variables before instantiating myJson1 to make sure they actually mean something. Even with the correct assignment statement, you'll still get an error if your JSON objects are defined the way they are right now.

So for example, this produces an error:

```
myJson1={
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2
}
myJson2={};
myJson2 = myJson1;
console.log(myJson2.key1);
```

This does not produce an error:

```
myJson1={
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2"
}
myJson2={};
myJson2 = myJson1;
console.log(myJson2.key1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using the wrong variable to assign to myJson2.

Should be

```
myJson2 = myJson1;
```

Comment: thank for the answer but I made a mistake on my post but I've checked I'm using the right variable